# How to set no stop bits in minicom?

Tags: usb, serial-port, minicom

How to set no stop bits in minicom?

Apparently, there is no such setting:

[image]

Would it be senseless?

I am trying to set this way since apparently (not sure) this is correct way to communicate via USB with arduino.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
minicom -b 9600 -o -D /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Note:

Use this command to list your usb devices if you are unsure of the device.

```
ls -lah /dev/ttyUSB*
```

Comment: Note to poor souls (such as myself) that end up reading this answer: It is not clear that it answers the question. The parameters proposed by @Paul do not tackle anything regarding the stop bit. And my issues remained.

Answer (score 0):

It is meaningless to set no stop bits. Without a stop bit the serial protocol could easily mistake a trailing 0-bit in one byte as the start bit in the next byte. You **must** have a stop bit. That guarantees that the current byte ends in a 1, and then a 0 starts the next byte.

As for the Arduino and USB, you do not need to set no stop bits to communicate with the Arduino. The communication between the Arduino and the USB port is done with USB protocol. The stop bits are only relevant at the Arduino end, on the USB serial interface chip.